# publishing angular website to github pages not working

Tags: angular, jekyll, github-pages

I am getting the following error when trying to publish. My [github repository](https://github.com/joevalook/globalWeatherVisualizer).

[image]

I tried using the angular cli gh pages extension, but that was not working for me, so I moved on to follow this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3HbnbT1Maw&ab_channel=BabatundeLamidi). Unfortunately I am at a loss.

Comment: Please include your error in the question and minimal code sample in your question of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, made a mistake in my committing and commited the docs folder to my ghpages branch, instead of the entire repository. Thus when github pages was looking for the docs folder to publish it wasn't available because this branch only had the inside of the docs folder. Made a new branch and committed the whole repo into, and now it publishes well.